# lxml library doesn't extract text in a given html tag when there is another tag with the text

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

I have the following html script:

```
<div>
    <p class="test1"> 
        <i class="empty"> </i> 
        WANTED TEXT 
    </p>
</div>
```

I want to extract the context of `p` tag (WANTED TEXT). My code:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO
html_parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tmp_xp = "//p[1]"
selected_tag = etree.parse(StringIO("""<div> <p class="test1"> <i class="empty"> </i> WANTED TEXT </p> </div>"""), html_parser).xpath(tmp_xp)
print(selected_tag[0].text)
```

The code prints nothing. If I move `WANTED TEXT` to before the `<i>` tag, the code starts to work fine.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Was your question sufficiently answered or are you still having problems?

Comment: @DanielHaley yes, it was answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `selected_tag[0]` use `.itertext()`:

```py
print("".join(selected_tag[0].itertext()).strip())
```

Prints:

```
WANTED TEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason `.text` doesn't work is that the text `WANTED TEXT` (along with the surrounding whitespace) is actually the `.tail` of the `i` element.

In addition to the `.join()`, `.itertext()`, and `.strip()` shown in another answer, you can also use plain XPath (`normalize-space()`).

Just change:

```py
print(selected_tag[0].text)
```

to:

```py
print(selected_tag[0].xpath("normalize-space()"))
```